Unique values constraint in Pulp
Can we directly model following constraint in pulp
x != y

as following:
constarint = pulp.LpConstraint(x != y)
model += constraint

Will this work as intended?
Here, x and y can take positive Integer values.

Actually it is a concept in CP rather than being in MIP. To use that in Pulp Please, search all-different constraint and its linearization.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1517850/651442

Will this work as intended? No.
Try it out and use
model.writeLP("nonsense.lp")

to verify what PuLP does with this. This is a good debugging tool in general.
Obviously, PuLP could handle this much better (e.g. by generating an exception). Defensive programming + operator overloading requires a lot of care even for operators you don't want to support.
Note. A good reference on how to implement AllDifferent constraints in a MIP model is: Williams, H. Paul and Yan, Hong (2001), Representations of the 'all_different' predicate of constraint satisfaction in integer programming, Informs Journal on Computing, 13 (2). 96-103.
